# Compare two git repositories to bring the older one up to date

Tags: git

I've got 2 remote git repositories RepA and RepB.
RepA is hosted on github and was at some point the basis for RepB. RepB is hosted on a hosting provider server and is up to date. I'd like to copy the updated files from RepB to RepA.
Theoretically, I could just copy everything from RepB to RepA (as it'll include the unchanged files as well as the more up to date ones) but I'd like to leave the unchanged files intact.
If I clone both repos locally, is there a way of identifying the files that differ or are new/deleted between the two repos? Or perhaps making RepoB as a new branch of RepoA and then merging? By the way, I'm only insterested in the master/main branches in both Repositories.
Thanks

Comment: When "comparing repositories", I would talk about histories that the two repositories have in common. It is strange that you talk about files that have been changed. Why do you not just check whether the two repositories have some history in common?

Comment: try `git diff path/to/RepA path/to/RepB`, but you will also get differences in their `.git` folder. You will probably need something like `--summary` or `--compact-summary`

Comment: Clone `repA`, add `repB` as a remote, push `repB/master` to `repA`.

Comment: Git is not about *files*. Git is about *commits*. You get (fetch) and give (push) *commits* from one repository to another. The commits then *contain* files, but you don't pick and choose one file at a time: you send and receive whole commits, which drag all their history with them (the commits themselves *are* the history, and later commits require earlier commits, which Git manages for you).